# listbox inside ScrollViewer - freeze program

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollview

I need some advice. We noticed unusual behavior within the ScrollViewer. I have a StackPanel with whom I am more items including ListBox when the StackPanel placed in a ScrollViewer, when loading data to the listbox, a program for a brief moment freezes. When I am alone ListBox but everything works normally, no freezing of the program.

Here is my code:

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="tStack"  >
            <Grid Height="300">

            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="300">

            </Grid>
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding AlbumsCvs.View, IsAsync=True}"
                           Style="{StaticResource ListBoxAlbumsTracksStyles}"
                           VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                           VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                           VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  >
                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlbumsHeader}" />
                </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            </ListBox>
         </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>   



<Style x:Key="ListBoxAlbumsTracksStyles" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>

                <DataTemplate >
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Border Background="#00000000"
                            Height="36" 
                            Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}">

                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TrackNumber"
                                       DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="2,0,5,0"

                                       Text="{Binding TrackNumber}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="13"
                                       MinWidth="17"
                                       Foreground="Black"/>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"                                               
                                            Text="{Binding TrackTitle}" 
                                            TextAlignment="Left"
                                            FontSize="13" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                            Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                           Text="{Binding Duration}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"   
                                           Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                           FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Right"/>                                    
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

    <!-- GroupItem -->
    <Style x:Key="AlbumsHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}" Background="#00000000">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,15">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}" 
                               DataContext="{Binding Items}" 
                               Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               FontSize="20" 
                               FontWeight="Light"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               Foreground="Black"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdAlbum}" 
                               DataContext="{Binding Items}" 
                               Margin="0,0,0,10" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               Foreground="Black"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

code behind:

```
 private async Task AlbumsArtistInformation()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ArtistName))
            return;

        ObservableCollection<AlbumsArtistCollections> _albumsArtistCollections = 
            new ObservableCollection<AlbumsArtistCollections>();

        try
        {
            var search = await spotifyDataService.GetArtists(ArtistName);
            if (search == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(search));



            foreach (var _artist in search.Artists.Items.Take(1))
            {
                this.IdArtist = _artist.Id;
            }


            var _artistAlbum = await spotifyDataService.GetArtistsAlbumsAsync(this.IdArtist, AlbumType.All);
            if (_artistAlbum == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_artistAlbum));

            _albumsArtistCollections = _artistAlbum;

        }
        finally
        {

            // Unbind to improve UI performance
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.Albums = null;
                this.AlbumsCvs = null;
            });




            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.Albums = _albumsArtistCollections;
            });




            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                // Populate CollectionViewSource
                this.AlbumsCvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = this.Albums };

                //Group by Album if needed
                this.AlbumsCvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("IdAlbum"));
            });


        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Ditch the StackPanel and use Grid the way it's made to be used. StackPanel won't invoke panel boundaries for things like scrolling and virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

Vertically oriented StackPanel provides an unbounded available space for the the `ListBox`, when it calls [MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx) method, during layout. Therefore, the `ListBox` (which by default uses virtualization) should create the whole items and this is why you program freezes for a moment.

Therefore, use a DockPanel instead:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="tStack" LastChildFill="True"  >
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="300">

    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="300">

    </Grid>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding AlbumsCvs.View, IsAsync=True}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListBoxAlbumsTracksStyles}"
                       VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                       VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                       VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  >
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlbumsHeader}" />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

`LastChildFill` is true by default. The ListBox should be the last element, in order to fill the space.

As another option, you can set the `Height` of the `ListBox` and put the `DockPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` or you can consider a `Grid` with splitters as another option.